# Websphere managesdk.bat -listAvailable / java.io.IOException: Unable to create lock manager

Tags: java, websphere, version

I'm trying to change the java version of websphere but returns me this error:

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\bin>managesdk.bat -listAvailable
!SESSION 2016-10-26 21:41:15.402 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20060921-0945
java.fullversion=JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.6 Windows 8 amd64-64 Compressed References 20160406_298378 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R26_Java626_SR8_20160406_0830_B298378
JIT  - tr.r11_20160328_114192
GC   - R26_Java626_SR8_20160406_0830_B298378_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20160406_298378
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -application com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher
Command-line arguments:  -application com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.WSLauncher

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-10-26 21:41:15.920
!MESSAGE Error reading configuration: Unable to create lock manager.
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Unable to create lock manager.
        at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.open(StorageManager.java:698)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.initFileManager(BaseStorage.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.initialize(BaseStorage.java:147)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.initializeStorage(BaseAdaptor.java:114)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.initialize(Framework.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.<init>(Framework.java:158)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:286)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:175)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:402)
```

already search about but do not think solution, thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you running under the same userid that installed WebSphere? Is it an admin? If not, did you recently run any commands like osgiCfgInit as an admin?

Answer (score 0):

If more commands are failing with the same osgi error, then there is an article that describes a possible cause as user covener stated , which could be a super user creating the config initially then a lesser user runnig commands, please see:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21578438